# C++: Method return List OR ref to list passed as parameter: Which is better

Tags: c++

Consider two skeleton implementations of methods that populate a list:

Approach one: Method returns a list.

```
std::list<std::string> fillList()
{
    std::list<std::string> result;

    // fill result

    return result;
}
```

called by:

```
std::list<std::string> lst = fillList();
```

Approach two: Method passed ref to list:

```
void fillList(std::list<std::string>& result)
{     
    // fill result

}
```

called by:

```
std::list<std::string> lst;
fillList(lst);
```

To me method one (return list) seems more elegant but seems less efficient as result has to be copied on method return which would not be good as the returned list could be very large. I choose a list for the example rather than a simple object because list size can vary significantly.

What is considered best pratice?

Comment: There's no _best practice_ about doing such. It totally depends on your actual use case and context, which form should be preferred. The 1st approach might involve an additional copy operation, but that's actually compiler specific.

Comment: This has been asked a million times... do you not search?

Comment: Why limit yourself to just one? Maybe both are desirable so you provide overloads. Why stop at just two, add `std::list<std::string>& fillList(std::list<std::string>&)` into the mix as well.